# The same Docker image and code line work locally but fails on server - how is it possible?

Tags: docker

My Groovy application inside Docker is failing with NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.withEagerDefault when run on AWS Fargate yet the very same docker image succeeds to run locally. Both run with the same env variables and the same code line is executed in both cases (as documented by the logs I can see from right before / right after). Yet in Fargate it fails. How is this even possible? It is the same set of JARs, the same Java version, the same OS (it is all inside the Docker image).

Here is how I run it locally:

`docker run -it --env AWS=true --env SERVER_PORT=9999 <my-account>.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/myapp-web`

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: How does it fail, what is the error message, what's in the logs, what is the local hardware/ host OS when you run it locally? Without any information about how it's failing we could only guess.

Comment: Additionaly consider memory and cpu constraints defined in AWS.

Comment: It fails with "NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.withEagerDefault", as described in the post, briefly after start, during the application initialization. I do not see how the local HW/OS could make the same line of code fail in such a way?

Comment: Good point about cpu / memory constraints but I do not think this plays any role either. The app has been running with the current settings for a month and only started failing after I changed how dependencies are packed in. I guess the issue could be different order of loading dependencies but I do not see how that would be possible when running inside the same Docker image, with the same OS and Java version and env variables.

Comment: I have the same issue with my Java libs. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I think it eventually went away, as things changed. So, sadly, I stil do not know the cause or a solution.